# certificate verify failed using pip install, main problem, (_ssl.c:1108)

Tags: ssl, pip, certificate, installation, verify

I've been trying to install python packages using:

```
pip install <package>
```

and all I get is:

"WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]
 certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)'))': /simple/pip/"

I know the code that can fix the problem, for which is (seldomly works):

```
pip3 install --trusted-host=pypi.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org --user <package>
```

but I want to know what is happening behind the scene, what's the core problem and how can I use pip like always!

I'd be tremendously happy if you could help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first write this

```
pip.ini
```

and now try to install packages
still if you are getting error then type this

```
pip install certifi
```

then write this

```
pip install Scrapy
```